# Syntax error for Range("J" & lastrow).Formula = "=Range"(H & lastrow" / 4000 & ")"

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write Range("H" & lastrow) / 4000
let's say lastrow = 150, i have tried H150 it works, however i need the number to be dynamically. So please help me

```
Range("J" & lastrow).Formula = "=Range"(H & lastrow" / 4000 & ")"
```

Comment: You are mixing vba syntax with Excel formula parameters. What is your goal? To actually input a formula in `J150` or to you want the value of `H150` devided by 4000? And do you eventually want to fill down a whole range of values? Your current attempt would work with: `Range("J" & lastrow).Formula = "=H" & lastrow & "/4000"`

Comment: Yes i want the H150 /4000

Comment: total = 100  
I would like to know, if instead divide by 4000, now let's say i want to divide by a variable total, how would u code it. Thank you bro!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While your initial problem was that you are mixing VBA syntax with Excel formula parameters, I also want to inform you that you might not need to input a formula. In the comments above you mentioned you just want the `H150 /4000`. The use of a formula seems redundant. Have a look at the two lines of codes below and see the difference.

```
Sub Test()

Dim lastrow As Long
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change sheetname according to yours
    lastrow = 150
    .Range("J" & lastrow).Formula = "=H" & lastrow & "/4000" 'This will input a formula
    .Range("J" & lastrow) = .Range("H" & lastrow) / 4000 'This will input the value directly
End With

End Sub
```

Now if you have a total that can differ, you can use another variable, e.g.: `total` to store that value and use in your code.

```
Sub Test()

Dim lastrow As Long, total as long
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change sheetname according to yours
    lastrow = 150
    total = 100
    .Range("J" & lastrow).Formula = "=H" & lastrow & "/" & total 'This will input a formula
    .Range("J" & lastrow) = .Range("H" & lastrow) / total'This will input the value directly
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Really appreciate what u have done for me friend, it saves me a lot of time for looking at other's posts. Again thank you so much friend.